# Building a shotmap in ggplot2 with facet_wrap and receive Error: width must be of length 1 or ncol - 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to plot a shotmap (locations on a field). I would like to use facet_wrap() or something similar to automatically repeat the plot for every team. The plot works if I do not include the facet_wrap() function, but I get this error when adding it.

`Error: width must be of length 1 or ncol - 1`

changes in code results in

```
facet_wrap(~Team, ncol = 1)
Error: height must be of length 1 or nrow - 1

facet_wrap(~Team, ncol = 1, ncol = 1)
Error in facet_wrap(~Team, ncol = 1, ncol = 1) : 
  formal argument "ncol" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Final piece to the puzzle, if I don't run the custom function, but rather just call ggplot() it works as expected (without the field).

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = shot_df2, aes(posX, posY, colour = Type)) +
  facet_wrap(~Team, ncol = 1)
p
```

So I'm assuming the error is with the custom function. Here's the custom function and sample data:

```
# final code
p <- create_StatsBomb_ShotMap("#ffffff", "#A9A9A9", "#ffffff", "#000000")
p + geom_point(data = shot_df2, aes(x=posX, y=posY, colour = Goal)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#F1BEBE", "#DF5058")) +
  facet_wrap(~Team, ncol = 1)

# data
shot_df2 <- tibble(
  Team = c("Team A", "Team A", "Team B", "Team B"), 
  Type = c("Shot on target", "Shot on target", "Goal", "Shot on target"),
    posX = c(21.6, 42.8, 38.8, 52.64), 
    posY = c(112.0, 105.7, 110.8, 97.6), 
    Goal = c("0", "0", "1", "0")
)

# custom function
create_StatsBomb_ShotMap <- function(grass_colour, line_colour, background_colour, goal_colour){
  
  theme_blankPitch = function(size=12) { 
    theme(
      #axis.line=element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
      axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
      #axis.ticks.y=element_text(size=size),
      #   axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.length=unit(0, "lines"), 
      #axis.ticks.margin=unit(0, "lines"), 
      axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
      axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
      legend.background=element_rect(fill=background_colour, colour=NA), 
      legend.key=element_rect(colour=background_colour,fill=background_colour), 
      legend.key.size=unit(1.2, "lines"), 
      legend.text=element_text(size=size), 
      legend.title=element_text(size=size, face="bold",hjust=0),
      strip.background = element_rect(colour = background_colour, fill = background_colour, size = .5),
      panel.background=element_rect(fill=background_colour,colour=background_colour), 
      #       panel.border=element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
      panel.spacing=element_blank(), 
      plot.background=element_blank(), 
      plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines"), 
      plot.title=element_text(size=size*1.2), 
      strip.text.y=element_text(colour=background_colour,size=size,angle=270),
      strip.text.x=element_text(size=size*1))}
  
  ymin <- 0 # minimum width
  ymax <- 80 # maximum width
  xmin <- 60 # minimum length
  xmax <- 120 # maximum length
  
  # Defining features along the length
  boxEdgeOff <- 102
  sixYardOff <- 114
  penSpotOff <- 108
  halfwayline <- 60
  
  # Defining features along the width
  boxEdgeLeft <- 18
  boxEdgeRight <- 62
  sixYardLeft <- 30 
  sixYardRight <- 50
  goalPostLeft <- 36
  goalPostRight <- 44
  CentreSpot <- 40   
  
  # other dimensions
  centreCirle_d <- 20   
  
  ## define the circle function
  circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
    r = diameter / 2
    tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
    xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
    yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
    return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
  }
  
  #### create leftD arc ####
  dArc <- circleFun(c((40),(penSpotOff)),centreCirle_d,npoints = 1000)
  ## remove part that is in the box
  dArc <- dArc[which(dArc$y <= (boxEdgeOff)),]
  
  ## initiate the plot, set some boundries to the plot
  p <- ggplot() + xlim(c(ymin,ymax)) + ylim(c(xmin,xmax)) +
    # add the theme 
    theme_blankPitch() +
    # add the base rectangle of the pitch 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=ymin, xmax=ymax, ymin=xmin, ymax=xmax), fill = grass_colour, colour = line_colour) +
    # add the 18 yard box offensive
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=boxEdgeLeft, xmax=boxEdgeRight, ymin=boxEdgeOff, ymax=xmax), fill = grass_colour, colour = line_colour) +
    # add the six yard box offensive
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=sixYardLeft, xmax=sixYardRight, ymin=sixYardOff, ymax=xmax), fill = grass_colour, colour = line_colour) +
    # add the arc circle 
    geom_path(data=dArc, aes(x=x,y=y), colour = line_colour) +
    # add penalty spot 
    geom_point(aes(x = CentreSpot , y = penSpotOff), colour = line_colour) +
    # add the goal offensive
    geom_segment(aes(x = goalPostLeft, y = xmax, xend = goalPostRight, yend = xmax),colour = goal_colour, size = 1)
  
  return(p)
  
}
```

FYI: The custom mapping function is not mine and can be found at https://github.com/FCrSTATS along with a lot of other quality features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message arises because you set `panel.spacing = element_blank()`. `panel.spacing`has to be a `unit` object, hence use `panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt")` to remove the spacing between panels.

However, even with this change facetting will not work but throws an error

`Error in gList(list(name = "background.1-11-18-1", gp = NULL, vp = NULL,  :  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`

Unfortunatly I can't tell you what's the problem with this issue here.

Nonetheless I have two solution approaches to solve this issue:

1. Add your dataset as an argument to your custom function and make it the global dataset by putting it in your call to `ggplot()`, e.g. try `ggplot(data = shots_df)`.
2. My preferred option would be to drop the call to ggplot() in the custom function and put all the layers in a list. Try this:

```r
# custom function
create_StatsBomb_ShotMap <- function(grass_colour, line_colour, background_colour, goal_colour){
  
  theme_blankPitch = function(size=12) { 
    theme(
      # #axis.line=element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
      axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
      #axis.ticks.y=element_text(size=size),
      axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.length=unit(0, "lines"), 
      #axis.ticks.margin=unit(0, "lines"), 
      axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
      axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
      legend.background=element_rect(fill=background_colour, colour=NA), 
      legend.key=element_rect(colour=background_colour,fill=background_colour), 
      legend.key.size=unit(1.2, "lines"), 
      legend.text=element_text(size=size), 
      legend.title=element_text(size=size, face="bold",hjust=0),
      strip.background = element_rect(colour = background_colour, fill = background_colour, size = .5),
      panel.background=element_rect(fill=background_colour,colour=background_colour), 
      #       panel.border=element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
      panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"), 
      plot.background=element_blank(), 
      #plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines"), 
      plot.title=element_text(size=size*1.2), 
      strip.text.y=element_text(colour=background_colour,size=size,angle=270),
      strip.text.x=element_text(size=size*1)
    )}
  
  ymin <- 0 # minimum width
  ymax <- 80 # maximum width
  xmin <- 60 # minimum length
  xmax <- 120 # maximum length
  
  # Defining features along the length
  boxEdgeOff <- 102
  sixYardOff <- 114
  penSpotOff <- 108
  halfwayline <- 60
  
  # Defining features along the width
  boxEdgeLeft <- 18
  boxEdgeRight <- 62
  sixYardLeft <- 30 
  sixYardRight <- 50
  goalPostLeft <- 36
  goalPostRight <- 44
  CentreSpot <- 40   
  
  # other dimensions
  centreCirle_d <- 20   
  
  ## define the circle function
  circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
    r = diameter / 2
    tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
    xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
    yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
    return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
  }
  
  #### create leftD arc ####
  dArc <- circleFun(c((40),(penSpotOff)),centreCirle_d,npoints = 1000)
  ## remove part that is in the box
  dArc <- dArc[which(dArc$y <= (boxEdgeOff)),]
  
  ## initiate the plot, set some boundries to the plot
  p <- list(
    xlim(c(ymin,ymax)),
    ylim(c(xmin,xmax)),
    # add the theme 
    theme_blankPitch(),
    # add the base rectangle of the pitch 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=ymin, xmax=ymax, ymin=xmin, ymax=xmax), fill = grass_colour, colour = line_colour),
    # add the 18 yard box offensive
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=boxEdgeLeft, xmax=boxEdgeRight, ymin=boxEdgeOff, ymax=xmax), fill = grass_colour, colour = line_colour),
    # add the six yard box offensive
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=sixYardLeft, xmax=sixYardRight, ymin=sixYardOff, ymax=xmax), fill = grass_colour, colour = line_colour),
    # add the arc circle 
    geom_path(data=dArc, aes(x=x,y=y), colour = line_colour),
    # add penalty spot 
    geom_point(aes(x = CentreSpot , y = penSpotOff), colour = line_colour),
    # add the goal offensive
    geom_segment(aes(x = goalPostLeft, y = xmax, xend = goalPostRight, yend = xmax),colour = goal_colour, size = 1)
  )
  
  return(p)
  
}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# data
shot_df2 <- tibble(
  Team = c("Team A", "Team A", "Team B", "Team B"), 
  Type = c("Shot on target", "Shot on target", "Goal", "Shot on target"),
  posX = c(21.6, 42.8, 38.8, 52.64), 
  posY = c(112.0, 105.7, 110.8, 97.6), 
  Goal = c("0", "0", "1", "0")
)

# final codd
ggplot(data = shot_df2) +
  create_StatsBomb_ShotMap("#ffffff", "#A9A9A9", "#ffffff", "#000000") +
  geom_point(aes(x=posX, y=posY, colour = Goal)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#F1BEBE", "#DF5058")) +
  facet_wrap(~Team, ncol = 1)
```

[image]